# .htaccess rule to redirect www.site.com/subDomainName to subDomainName.site.com

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I am not so well versed with regular expressions and .htaccess rewrites and redirects. I have the following :

```
www.site.com/subDomainName
```

and I want it redirected to

```
subDomainName.site.com.
```

I was able to get some code to do the redirect but it kept being pointed to www.subDomainName.site.com.

Comment: What was the code that failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subDomainName\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subDomainName(.*)$ http://subDomainName.site.com$1 [L,R]
```

To make the redirect permanent, change the `R` flag in the square brackets to `R=301`.

Comment: Sorry it actually worked, I was missing some stuff in apache config. Thank you for your help.